# React Native, Calling a Function from Another one in Render

Tags: javascript, html, function, react-native

I have this SMN() function and I've created inside it Site function as Const. So I need to call Site function in Render() function. This is main function code:

```
SMN() {
    const Site = () => {
            return (
                <View style={{ height: 400 }}>
                    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
                </View>
        );
     }
});
```

This is Render() function where I want to call Site function from it, I've used:
this.SMN().Site , this does not throw errors but does not display any.

```
render() {
    return (
         </View>
            <View>{this.SMN().Site}</View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a function inside another function?

Answer (score 1):

Make your Site as a component just like this:

```
const Site = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{ height: 400 }}>
                <WebView 
                    source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }} 
                    style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
            </View>
    );
 }
```

And in your render function use it like this:

```
render() {
    return (
         </View>
            <View><Site /></View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Chaliem I got this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Site`

Comment: did you forgot to import Site?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the return you want from SMN(). So this is what I thought your intended solution was.

```
SMN() {
   
            return (
                {
                 Site : () => (
                                  <View style={{ height: 400 }}>
                                    <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }} 
                                             style={{marginTop:20 }} />
                                   </View>
                               )
                 }
               );
             
});
```

```
render() {
    return (
         </View>
            <View>{this.SMN().Site}</View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: @Changboon Lee, I got this error: `TypeError: this.SMN is not a function. (In 'this.SMN()', 'this.SMN' is undefined)`

Comment: @HowardJohn Please show me all the codes that that code is working on.